# hadoop.security.authentication: simple

Tags: hadoop

i have the following configuration in core-site.xml
***Hadoop Version 3.3.x***

```
hadoop.http.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed: "false"
hadoop.http.authentication.type: simple
hadoop.http.filter.initializers: org.apache.hadoop.security.AuthenticationFilterInitializer
```

getting the following error when starting bootstrap namenode.

```
"caught exception initializing http://apache-hadoop-journalnode-2.apache-hadoop-journalnode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local:8480/getJournal?jid=apache-hadoop-namenode&segmentTxId=1&storageInfo=-66%3A1139640761%3A1664180726776%3ACID-9f32eb78-6efb-46ed-afd4-715e6c598e01&inProgressOk=true","exceptionclass":"org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.HttpGetFailedException","stack":["org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.HttpGetFailedException: Fetch of http://apache-hadoop-journalnode-2.apache-hadoop-journalnode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local:8480/getJournal?jid=apache-hadoop-namenode&segmentTxId=1&storageInfo=-66%3A1139640761%3A1664180726776%3ACID-9f32eb78-6efb-46ed-afd4-715e6c598e01&inProgressOk=true failed with status code 401","Response message:","Authentication required","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream$URLLog$1.run(EditLogFileInputStream.java:489)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream$URLLog$1.run(EditLogFileInputStream.java:474)","\tat java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)","\tat javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1878)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsUser(SecurityUtil.java:536)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsCurrentUser(SecurityUtil.java:530)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream$URLLog.getInputStream(EditLogFileInputStream.java:473)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream.init(EditLogFileInputStream.java:157)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream.nextOpImpl(EditLogFileInputStream.java:218)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogFileInputStream.nextOp(EditLogFileInputStream.java:276)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.readOp(EditLogInputStream.java:85)","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.EditLogInputStream.skipUntil(EditLogInputStream.java:151)"
```

works fine when hadoop.http.authentication.simple.anonymous.allowed: "true" but not when set to false

```
curl -s http://localhost:9870/jmx?qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus
 {
  "beans" : [ {
  "name" : "Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus",
  "modelerType" : "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode",
  "NNRole" : "NameNode",
  "HostAndPort" : "apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local:8020",
  "SecurityEnabled" : false,
  "LastHATransitionTime" : 1664300715338,
  "BytesWithFutureGenerationStamps" : 0,
  "SlowPeersReport" : null,
  "SlowDisksReport" : null,
  "State" : "active"
  } ]
}
```

but fails to show details when i use curl -s http://localhost:9870/jmx?***user.name=hdfs***&qry=Hadoop:service=NameNode,name=NameNodeStatus

similar authentication is seen in bootstrapstandby node when doing ***imageTransfer?getImage*** endpoint

```
message":"Failed to start namenode.","exceptionclass":"java.io.IOException","stack":["java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.HttpGetFailedException: Image transfer servlet at http://apache-hadoop-namenode-0.apache-hadoop-namenode.nom-backend.svc.cluster.local:9870/imagetransfer?getimage=1&txid=0&storageInfo=-66:1919632792:1664433837683:CID-462fba6c-76bc-4c4f-958e-c4906374d825&bootstrapstandby=true failed with status code 401","Response message:","Authentication required","\tat org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.ha.BootstrapStandby.run(BootstrapStandby.java:549)"
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-15860

Comment: i see this bug in apache, but there is no solution  i guess. can anyone help ?